# Use of the global keyword in Python

Tags: python

I have a simple Python script which just multiplies two numbers taken from a list of list and then send the results to another function which then appends them to a list. Below is the code for the same:

```
results = []

def check_results(result):
    results.append(result)

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]
    for x, y in numbers:
        check_results(multiply(x, y))
    print(results)
```

My question is should we not use the global keyword inside the check_results function before we add them to the results list which is outside its scope ?

In other words shouldn't the whole code be something like this ?

```
results = []

def check_results(result):
    global results
    results.append(result)

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]
    for x, y in numbers:
        check_results(multiply(x, y))
    print(results)
```

Can someone kindly let me know if my understanding is wrong here and what should the global keyword be used for?

Comment: no, `results` is already in the global scope, the `global` keyword is used to define variables that would be local to the function to global scope (usable in other functions).

Comment: If this question is about style, I would use `results` as an additional parameter to `check_results` (or use an object-oriented approach).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python

- *writes* in the local scope
- *reads* from the local scope, and if that fails, from the global scope

So, if you wanted to *assign* the global `results` variable, you would have to use `global results`, to specify that you mean the global variable.

However, since you *read* `results`, and no such variable exists in your function, the global one is looked up.

Note that, although you append to the list referred to by `results`, you don't change the actual `results` variable itself, so what you do is not considered writing.

Comment: You can add that we can, with the `global` keyword make Python *writes* to global scope from one or several functions (local scope) to reuse a variable that is not initially set in the global scope

Comment: @Nenri: good point, but I didn't want go beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: I think it's in the *scope* (good pun :p) of the original question because he asked what's the usage of `global`

Comment: and, to complete the answer, you can add informations about `nonlocal` and `local` keywords but that's optionnal i think